# Displaying an arrow for indicating user to scroll up or down in a UITableView in objective c

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uitableview

I want to display an arrow which indicates the user to scroll up or down in a table depending on the data in the table.

i.e Down arrow indicating user to scroll down or Up arrow indicating scroll up.

How can i gt the current status of the table to display arrows?

Many Thanks,

Avi.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since UITableView is the subclass of UIScrollView. Implement the followin UIScrollView delegate in you view controller:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if (tableView.contentOffset.y < 
        tableView.contentSize.height - tableView.frame.size.height)
        downArrow.hidden = NO;
    else
        downArrow.hidden = YES;

    if (tableView.contentOffset.y > 0) 
        upArrow.hidden = NO;
    else
        upArrow.hidden = YES; 
}
```

DownArrow and uparrow shoulf be your images placed at the appropriate positions on your view.